# Restoring view SavedState throws ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling parent view SavedState

Tags: android, parcelable, savestate, parcel

I have 2 classes `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`:

`ParentClass` is a subclass of RelativeLayout which saves state using onSaveInstanceState() / onRestoreInstanceState() with following code:

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    SavedState savedState = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
    savedState.someObj = someObj;
    savedState.someInt = someInt;
    savedState.someEnum = someEnum;
    return savedState;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable in) {
    if (!(in instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(in);
        return;
    }
    SavedState savedState = (SavedState) in;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
    this.someObj = savedState.someObj;
    this.someInt = savedState.someInt;
    this.someEnum = savedState.someEnum;
}
```

And here is the `SavedState` code:

```
public static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {

    private SomeObj someObj;
    private int someInt;
    private SomeEnum someEnum;

    public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    public SavedState(Parcel source) {
        super(source);
        someInt = source.readInt();
        someEnum = SomeEnum.values()[source.readInt()];
        someObj = source.readParcelable(SomeObj.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeInt(someInt);
        dest.writeInt(someEnum.ordinal());
        dest.writeParcelable(someObj, flags);
    }

    public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Creator<SavedState>() {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SavedState(in);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Nothing fancy, everything works as expected (saving \ restoring state) when I use this view directly.

Then I have `ChildClass` which extends `ParentClass` It also saves it state using exactly same code, except that I am saving only long and int fields.

When the app tries to restore `ChildClass` view state by calling it `SavedState` constructor with `Parcel` from `CREATOR` it crashes with following stack:

```
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.company.app.ParentClass$SavedState
1   android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator Parcel.java, line 2320
2   android.os.Parcel.readParcelable    Parcel.java, line 2270
3   android.view.AbsSavedState.<init>   AbsSavedState.java, line 57
4   android.view.View$BaseSavedState.<init> View.java, line 20128
5   com.company.app.ChildClass$SavedState.<init>    ChildClass.java, line 151
6   com.company.app.ChildClass$SavedState$1.a   ChildClass.java, line 166
7   com.company.app.ChildClass$SavedState$1.createFromParcel ChildClass.java, line 164
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Make your **SavedState** class implement **Parcelable**

```
public static class SavedState extends Parcelable {
```

Comment: `SavedState` extends `BaseSavedState` which extends `AbsSavedState` which implements `Parcelable`, so I don't think it will help